# Trouble trying to add label to grouping of datetime interval in CSV using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, intervals

I'm trying to add a label to each 15-minute interval in a new column of my Pandas df called Interval if the datetime falls within a 15-minute range.
I've tried cut, qcut, strptime and grouper to no avail.

```
'''Basically I'd like to turn this:'''
    Date
    29/8/20 2:24       
    29/8/20 1:02
    29/8/20 0:26
    28/8/20 23:14
    28/8/20 21:57
    28/8/20 21:55
    28/8/20 21:46
    28/8/20 20:38
    28/8/20 19:40
    28/8/20 18:20
    
 '''Into this:'''
    Date             Interval
    29/8/20 2:24     Period 1
    29/8/20 1:02     Period 2
    29/8/20 0:26     Period 3
    28/8/20 23:14    Period 4
    28/8/20 21:57    Period 5
    28/8/20 21:55    Period 5
    28/8/20 21:46    Period 5
    28/8/20 21:35    Period 5
    28/8/20 19:40    Period 6
    28/8/20 18:20    Period 7
```

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

s_date = datetime.datetime.now()
dates = [s_date]
for days in range(1, 5):
    for i in range(24 * 4):
        dates.append(dates[-1] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15))
    dates.append(dates[0] + datetime.timedelta(days=days))

print(dates)

df['Interval'] = pd.cut(df['Date'], bins=dates, duplicates='drop', ordered=True, labels=labels,
                        right=False).cat.add_categories([i]).fillna(i)

# Save CSV File
csv_path = r'x'
df.to_csv(csv_path + 'x' + '.csv')
```

Comment: The logic to create `Interval` doesn't make any sense. Please explain the logic in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't explain very well, but I think I know what you are trying to accomplish. This problem is all about ORDER. With `.grouper` and `.cut`, ORDER is not relevant. As such, you need to use `.shift()` for row-wise comparisons.

Essentially, it sounds like you are trying to bin times together in the same period if the next row is within 15 minutes. You can use `.shift()` to compare data from one row to the next and calculate if the seconds are > 900 (i.e. 15 minutes) with `dt.seconds > 900`. This will return a series of `True` or `False`. Then, simply take the `.cumsum()` (which adds `1` when there is a `True` value and `0` when `False`. Finally, you can change the dtype to a string with `.astype(str)` and prepend `'Period ' +` to the beginning:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Interval'] = 'Period ' + (((df.shift()['Date'] - df['Date']).dt.seconds > 900).cumsum() + 1).astype(str)

Out[5]: 
                 Date  Interval
0 2020-08-29 02:24:00  Period 1
1 2020-08-29 01:02:00  Period 2
2 2020-08-29 00:26:00  Period 3
3 2020-08-28 23:14:00  Period 4
4 2020-08-28 21:57:00  Period 5
5 2020-08-28 21:55:00  Period 5
6 2020-08-28 21:46:00  Period 5
7 2020-08-28 20:38:00  Period 6
8 2020-08-28 19:40:00  Period 7
9 2020-08-28 18:20:00  Period 8
```

Comment: Note that my expected output is different than yours, because there is an error in your `Date` column, where the value in the 8th row is different between input/output.

Comment: This is great thank you so much; however, one problem I am facing is that datetime rows are being binned together if they are within 15 minutes of each other. Is there anyway to only bin datetime rows based on the first datetime item within the list rather then looking at it consequtively?